# Simple Facebook Connect in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, facebook

Does anyone have a simple and successful demo implementation of facebook connect in an google app engine application. I am developing an web application and want facebook connect to be the primary method for logging in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to use Google login, should also work with Facebook.

I had some troubles with the implementation, but [this tutorial](http://artandlogic.com/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/) really helped me.

Comment: Thanks, I'l keep that in mind next time. However, I think this question is too vague to provide an actual answer.