# App Engine and Facebook: which libraries to use?

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, facebook

I will be developing a web application with Google App Engine that will use Facebook Connect as the only means of registering / logging in.  The web app will be written in Python.  I need to know their name, profile pic, how many friends the user has, as well as their age and also possibly location, relationship status, work info, etc. (although those are mostly optional besides name, pic, age and friend count).

There seem to be a number of libraries that can do the task.  There is the official Facebook Javascript SDK, minifb, and pyfacebook to name a few.

How do you think I should go about this task?  Which libraries should I use, and what are the pros / cons?

Also to be considered is how well documented the code is and how widely it is used.  If you can provide links to relevant example code / documentation, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Facebook python-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk/tree/master/examples/appengine) has an example application to use Facebook connect with Google App Engine. I guess, you are looking for the same.

Comment: I didn't realize Facebook had an official solution.  One would think this information would be easier to find in a Google Search than obsolete libraries.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment for the answer which suggests using the Facebook python-sdk.

Note that at github it [says](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk)

> This SDK is deprecated. It does not support the new cookie format that
>   we rolled out as part of the OAuth Migration. In short, it doesn't
>   work.

I've had success with the [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) project, which I believe is a fork of Facebook's original (and now dead) python-sdk project noted above. However you may also wish to check out [EngineAuth](http://code.scotchmedia.com/engineauth/docs/index.html#acquiring-client-keys).

Comment: That's strange.  In my mind deprecated means it is obsolete but still supported.  Saying it doesn't work seems like they are contradicting themselves.

Comment: Also could you link the source of that statement?

Comment: @Muhd - Edited to add link, as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check out this similar question asked by another StackOverflow user:

[Simple Facebook Connect in Google App Engine (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512658/simple-facebook-connect-in-google-app-engine-python)

There are some links provided here that sound exactly like what you're looking for.

Comment: I saw that already.  One link is broken and the other is a page I have seen before.

Answer (score 0):

For all specified detail you need to go with respective [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from users and then you can extract all specific information you needed.

You can go by either [Graph Api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) or [Javascript Api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

But with javascript you need to use many ajax request through your application where graph api only need access_token once for particular instance and also independent of client action.

Graph API also helps you in preventing use of other framework like pyfacebook, minifb, etc.

Apart from pros and cons you can also look some example code for both [javascript and graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690723/facebook-graph-api-and-django/5539531#5539531)

Hope this information will be useful to you.